# Clone Specific content of the div and put in other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have a little problem when i try to clone an element with jquery basically I Have this, i want to clone the div called clone and put in other div in some where else.

```
<li class="jqModal"  >
    <div class="clone">
    <div class="image">
            <img src="<?php echo $products[$j]['thumb']; ?>"
                 title="<?php echo $products[$j]['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $products[$j]['name']; ?>" />
    </div>
    <h2><a href=""><?php echo $products[$j]['name']; ?></a></h2>
    <strong class="price"><?php echo $products[$j]['price']; ?></strong>
    <a href="<?php echo $products[$j]['href']; ?>">More details</a>
    </div>


</li>`
```

I use this in my document ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".product-list li").hover(
      function () {
         //replace image and id
         $var = $(this).clone(false).find("#clone").
         $('#div-to-replace').replaceWith($var);
      }
   );
});
```

But its not working any advice, thank you in advance. :)

Comment: $(".product-list li") won't select anything if you don't have a <li> tag with the "product-list" class :/

Comment: $('.product-list li') will select all LI elements which are inside of some element with the class "product-list". So I think, the wrapping elemt is "missing" in the code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".product-list li").hover(
    function () {
        //replace image and id
        $var = $('.clone', this).clone();
        $('#div-to-replace').replaceWith($var);
    }
);
```

Changes to your code:

1. You want to clone the element with the **class** "clone", not the id: #clone -> .clone
2. If you clone first and then find the element, then you're cloning too much, so I changed the selector for cloning
3. At the end of this line there's a dot where should be a semicolon.​

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 problems that I see here, first this line:

```
$var = $(this).clone(false).find("#clone").
```

You need a `;` at the end instead of a `.` so you don't get a syntax error, and also `clone` is the **class** not the `#ID`, so you need `.find('.clone')`.  Then here:

```
$('#div-to-replace').replaceWith($var);
```

That `<div>` you're replacing would be totally gone, so it wouldn't work next time around, I think what you want is this:

```
var product = $(this).find('.clone').clone();
$('#div-to-replace').empty().append(product);
```

This doesn't replace the `#div-to-replace` but instead puts the content in there, otherwise you would be missing the `<div>` when you hovered the *next* product.  Also be sure to use `var` when creating local variables so it doesn't product unwanted side-effects with the global variable you get without it :)